# JasperReports + TimeSeriesChart: Month Data, Year labels

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, timeserieschart

I've been using JasperReports to produce a PDF report but there's this one feature that I can't get to work. I'm trying to produce a TimeSeriesCharts that has monthly data but only shows the year labels. Unfortunately this is the end result:

[image]

I would like that each year only shows up once. How can I do it?

jrxml code below:

```
<timeSeriesChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report" isShowLegend="false">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="462" height="180" />
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <timeSeriesDataset timePeriod="Month">
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="chartDataSet" uuid="abec2dce-b670-4e84-b71f-469d954dbcb5">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{data})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <timeSeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{serie}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <timePeriodExpression><![CDATA[$F{category}]]></timePeriodExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></valueExpression>
                    </timeSeries>
                </timeSeriesDataset>
                <timeSeriesPlot isShowShapes="false">
                    <plot>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#0000FF" />
                    </plot>
                    <timeAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000" verticalTickLabels="true" tickLabelMask="yyyy" />
                    </timeAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </timeSeriesPlot>
            </timeSeriesChart>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was quite easy. I had to create a Java class used to customize the chart:

```
public class MyChartCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer {
@Override
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart){
    DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis();
    axis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.YEAR, 1));
}
}
```

And then just reference it in the jrxml:

```
<timeSeriesChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report" isShowLegend="false" customizerClass="my.org.MyChartCustomizer">
....
```

Hope this helps someone.